# open url in android app oncreate (only works some of the time)

Tags: android, web

I want to open an url in the browser when the user taps on the app. I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }
}
```

But this only works the first time you open the app. If you navigate back to the home page and re open the app, it just goes to a blank layout with the app's name on top. How do I ensure that the link always opens?

EDIT:
I added onResume:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume();

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add call to `finish()` after `startActivity(browserIntent)`. In this case the method `onCreate(...)` of your activity will be always called next time a user opens your application.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is called when the activity is created, getting back to the main menu and enter again doesn't grant you to recreate the activity from 0.

If you want this behaviour always, move your code to `onResume()`

Comment: I updated the code. Why does it still not work though?

Comment: Anyway, maybe you need to think why you need an activity just for launching a web

Answer (score 0):

use onResume() because onCreate() method called only once